# reading token on python

Tags: python, token

I want to read token from a text document and check for particular keyword. How would I do that?
For example my file looks like this:

```
<protein id="Q11" name="HUMAN" length="655" crc64="30E1C1D138">
    <match id="G3DSA:3.30.160.60" name="ZC2f_H2/iegse_NA-bd" dbname="GE3D" status="T" evd="HMPfm">
      <ipr id="IPR013087" name="Zinc finger, H2-type/inrase, D-bindg" tpe="Dain" />
      <ln stt="114" end="142" sc="1.0E-8" />
    </match>
```

(I want to skip the first line and search for token on the second line for dbname must be equal to GE3D. If it is I want to store the stt number and end number.)

*so i did this but I don't know why it only return me one number for start and for end, since more than one number should be satisfy the requirement:
from lxml import entree

filename = 'inQ14591.txt'

with open(filename,'rb') as f:

```
root = etree.parse(f)
for ln in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='GE3D']/ln"):
    start = ln.get("stt")
    end = ln.get("end")
```

print (stt)

print end

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: That looks like XML, have you tried writing a parser using lxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can parse it with `BeautifulSoup`, but I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
text = '''<protein id="Q11" name="HUMAN" length="655" crc64="30E1C1D138">
    <match id="G3DSA:3.30.160.60" name="ZC2f_H2/iegse_NA-bd" dbname="GE3D" status="T" evd="HMPfm">
      <ipr id="IPR013087" name="Zinc finger, H2-type/inrase, D-bindg" tpe="Dain" />
      <ln stt="114" end="142" sc="1.0E-8" />
    </match>'''

soup= BeautifulSoup(text)

res=soup.findAll(dbname='GE3D')
```

Update per your comment to find the `stt` value, you need to find the line with `ln` then take the tag with `stt` like so:

```
stt_value = soup.findAll('ln')[0]['stt'] # u'114'
end_value = soup.findAll('ln')[0]['end'] # u'142'
```

Comment: Thank you very much TankorSmash. I have very multiple data similar to this. Would it be possible if it find dbname=GE3D and capture the the 114 from ln stt="114" and 142 from end="142" on the one that has dbname =GE3D.

Comment: For sure, you'd just need to play around with the `soup.findAll()`. Take a look at the docs here `http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The basic find method: findAll(name, attrs, recursive, text, limit, **kwargs)` It's really simple after you get the hang of it

Comment: I tried using your method but it said that index out of range when i add stt_value... and end_value.

Comment: Make sure that the string you're passing to `findAll` is `ln` and not `In`. Try printing the result of `findAll` like so: `print soup.findAll('ln')` to make sure the list you're parsing is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like XML, you can use that to your advantage.

```
from lxml import etree

filename = "somefilename" # change this

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    root = etree.parse(f)
    for ln in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='GE3D']/ln"):
        stt = ln.get("stt")
        end = ln.get("end")
        print "%s, %s" % (stt, end, )
        # do something else with stt and end
```

Comment: Thank you very much cha0site. Will this allow me to get stt and end number from the portion of text with dbname =GE3D in it? The reason i am asking is that i have multiple of similar text like above on one file with and without dbname ='GE3D'..thanks again

Comment: @ChadD: As long as the "text" is (mostly) valid XML, yes. The loop will iterate over every `match` tag that has a `dbname` of `GE3D`.

Comment: I tried it and see if it prints list of numbers but instead it prints only one number for start and one number for end. ( i just add print stt and print end below your code.) thanks

Comment: @ChadD: Well, yes, I see that you put the print statement outside the loop. I've edited the answer. If you want the values in a list, you could do that instead of printing.